# Getting Session Object in Tomcat Custom Realm

Tags: tomcat, jdbcrealm

I am using Tomcat realm with FORM authentication. And after authentication is done I want to save an object inside the session but couldn't figure out how to get session.

```
import org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase;

public class MyRealm extends RealmBase {

    @Override
    public Principal authenticate(String username, String credentials) {

        // get session here
        return super.authenticate(username, credentials);
    }
```

The reason for that is I had an login servlet before and was using my own authentication, now I need to switch to Tomcat Realm and basically migrate login servlet code to my custom realm class. After login is successful I need to create an object which holds session specific objects and put it inside the current session. And I need the username & password to create it so authenticate() method seems only place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I always do this is with a `Filter` that runs *after* the authentication has been completed. If the `HttpSession` contains a user token, then I do nothing and call-down the chain. If the `HttpSession` does not contain that user token, I do everything I need to do to set-up the session using the `Principal` available from the request (because authentication has already occurred).

It doesn't sound like this really needs to be part of authentication (the Realm), so separate the two.